# AngularJS, factory, do POST then GET method

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i'm having a little problems when doing REST requests with AngularJS.
I have server part done in PHP(Laravel), I tested it with POSTMAN and it's working fine. I just have POST /expression where i send json like `{"expression":"(2+5)"}` and I would get json like `{"expression":"(2+5)","result":"7"}`, when I do several POST request I'll need the results to be concatenated on my result.html page. I wrote app.js for route providing, and i have contoller.js

```
//post expression
myApp.controller('expressionController', ['$scope', 'postExpressionFactory', 'getExpressionFactory','$location',
    function ($scope, postExpressionFactory,getExpressionFactory, $location) {
        $scope.postNewExpression = function () {
            $scope.results = postExpressionFactory.evaluate({'expression':$scope.expression});
            console.log($scope.results.expression);
            console.log($scope.results.result);
        };
    }]);
```

and have factory in services.js

```
//post factory
myServices.factory('postExpressionFactory', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('../server.php/expression', {}, {
            evaluate: {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, isArray: false}
        });
    }]);
```

and have the html that calls this post request

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Enter expression</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">=</span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="expression" name="result" ng-model="expression" ng-required="true">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="postNewExpression()">Calculate</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="res in results">
                    <a class="list-group-item">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.expression}}</h4>
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.result}}</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Angular is running fine, I think i'm not getting json right, when i execute this in mozilla->network i see that i have done POST request and I get json respone result:"7", expression:(2+5). How can i get this result -> 7 in results.expression, results.result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $scope.results object is defined as having two properties, but when you iterate it in an ng-repeat, you try to access properties of strings that don't exist, so it fails silently.

```
// your results object:
$scope.results = postExpressionFactory.evaluate({'expression':$scope.expression});

// so your object looks like this:
{
    expression: something,
    result: somethingElse,
}
```

The way you attempt to access it:

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="res in results">
     <a class="list-group-item">
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.expression}}</h4>
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.result}}</h4>
     </a>
</div>
```

See error in HTML here by printing your object:

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="res in results">
     {{ result }}
     <a class="list-group-item">
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.expression}}</h4>
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{res.result}}</h4>
     </a>
</div>

// what you probably want is an array for the results, then push onto the array
$scope.results = [];

// push
$scope.results.push(postExpressionFactory.evaluate({'expression':$scope.expression}));
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But i have one more question, when i do this post request i have another type of answer from server, json looks like {expression:'5+7',token:'a123'}, now i need to get this token value and do get request if token exists. I tried several times but i can not access $scope.expression.token, how can i do this if you understand me. My logic is something like this: if ($scope.results.expressionId !== undefined) {
$scope.getNewExpression = function () {                  $scope.results.push(getExpressionFactory.result($scope.results.expressionId));};}

Comment: (i assume that i'll have to pop the last member if token exists)