# AngularJS, do POST then GET request

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I have already started question about this on [AngularJS, factory, do POST then GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199156/angularjs-factory-do-post-than-get-method). I have to do POST request get json like `{'exp':'2+3','token':'asd'}`(SoluableNonagon answerd me very well), then get the token from json and to GET request like /something/:token, before that I'll have to check if token exist in json that i got with POST method. Can anyone tell me how can I do this and how can I call factory from controller that is doing post request?

Answer (score 0):

every $http functions returns a promise, promises can be nested or serialized the return inside the function must be a promise in order to serialize your operations, the next then will be called when the $http.get is finally finished.

```
$http.post('post1').then(function (resultPost1) {

   // do your stuff

   return $http.get('get1');

}).then(function (resultGet1) {

   // do your stuff

   return $http.get('get2').then(function (resultGet2) {

       // do your nested stuff

       return $http.get('get3');
   });

}).then(function (resultGet3) {

    // do your stuff

});
```

More info on $q docs: https://github.com/kriskowal/q